# Edges Need to be smooth from blender to Substance

Tags: modifiers

I have tried the smooth modifier in blender and had no luck.  I have prominent seams when I am trying to texture the model after leaving blender 3.9.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have autosmooth sharp edges in an area without uv seams. Anywhere that you have a "sharp" edge split on a model you have to have a uv seam (though not necessarily the other way around.

This is because when you set an edge as sharp what it essentially does is tell   each vertex on the sharp edge "Pretend to be two vertices at once".

You can actually see this by checking turning on *Split Vertex Normals* in the overlay panel.

Shade Smooth > Autosmooth:

[image]

Flat shaded:  (Each vertex is essentially duplicated for each face it's a part of, at least as far as normals are concerned).

[image]

Smooth Shaded, no autosmooth:

[image]

Right now you are trying to tell the uv to represent two different vertices in the same UV shell and it's basically deciding on one or the other for each pixel.

[image]

I would go back and clear all sharps on this model, a tree model generally speaking isn't going to need any kind of split normals anyways. But in the future remember that any split edges have to have a uv seam.

Comment: This is a great answer

Comment: thank you for that.  I figured it out with help.  You had the same answer.  In maya you just select all the edges and soften edges.  I am new to blender so I am getting the hang of it.  Thank you again.